# Moving HTML content from SQL database to XML file for Wordpress import

Tags: html, xml

I am moving content from a ColdFusion based custom website storing data in a SQL database to Wordpress. I wrote CF code to create a XML doc. However I of course need to parse some of the values so need to be able to see the string. The problem I have is that all of the tools I have render the HTML space as a space and not for example `&nbsp;`.

Here is a sample of the SQL data :

```
the church where he was destined to become famous.
        Boston was
```

Note the spaces before the word Boston. All I need to know is the actual text value so I can do a find and replace. Any idea on a tool that lets you see this?

Comment: I see that when I gave the example above of the string "&nbsp;" it shows as a space in the question.  Trying putting it in quotes

Answer (score 0):

This tool lets you see the unrendered HTML text so I was able to do the search and replaces needed to clean up the data.

https://onlinestringtools.com/url-encode-string